# Facebook Graph API Paging in Batches

Tags: php, facebook, api

I am struggling to understand how to make use of the paging mechanism with batch requests to Facebook's Graph API.

My issue with the code below is that despite attempting to track an offset for each `facebook_id` that is in my database, I'm unable to determine when a particular request has come up empty and therefore shouldn't be requested again.

I'm parsing the `facebook_id`'s from the paging array in the responses. At the point when no more posts are available, FB returns an empty `data` array and therefore I'm unable to recognize *which* request has no more pages, and thus reduce the subsequent requests. Each time I'm querying FB with `$fb_batch_limit` urls despite the fact not all requests have returned a paging token from the previous call.

How would a real programmer tackle this problem?

```
    $posts = array();

    //$fb_batch_limit = 30;
    $fb_batch_limit = 2;
    $fb_req_limit=10;

    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
            'appId'  => $fb_app_id,
            'secret' => $fb_app_secret
    ));
    $facebook->setAccessToken($fb_user_token);
    $index = 0;
    $since = '1Jan14';
    $until = 'today';

    $num_records_res = $oDB->select("SELECT count(*) as count FROM facebook f");
    $num_records_row = mysqli_fetch_array($num_records_res);
    $num_records = $num_records_row['count'];
    while($index < $num_records) {
            printf("# %d to %d\n", $index, $index+$fb_batch_limit);
            $res = $oDB->select("SELECT facebook_id FROM facebook f ".
                                "LIMIT $index, $fb_batch_limit");
            $index = $index + $fb_batch_limit;
            $offsets = array();
            while($rr = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
                    $offsets[$rr['facebook_id']] = 0;
            }
            if (!count($offsets)) {
                    printf("no more accounts\n");
                    break;
            }

            $r=1;
            do {
                    $urls = array();
                    foreach ($offsets as $fbid => $offset) {
                            $tmp["method"] = 'GET';
                            $tmp["relative_url"] = "/".$fbid."/feed?fields=likes.limit(1).summary(true)&offset=$offset&limit=$fb_req_limit";//&since=$since&until=$until";
                            $tmp["include_headers"] = false;
                            $urls[] = $tmp;
                    }
                    $numurls = count($urls);
                    printf("$r: fetching %d urls have %d posts\n", $numurls, count($posts));
                    $response = $facebook->batch($urls);
                    foreach ($response as $result) {
                            if (array_key_exists("error", $result)) {
                                    //FIXME handle rate limits somehow
                                    print_r($result);
                                    die;
                            }
                            if (array_key_exists("paging", $result)) {
                                    $fbid = substr(parse_url($result['paging']['previous'])['path'],6);
                                    $fbid = substr($fbid, 0, -5);

                                    if (($count = count($result['data'])) > 0) {
                                            $posts = array_merge($posts, $result['data']);
                                            if (array_key_exists("paging", $result) && array_key_exists("next", $result["paging"])) {
                                                    if (array_key_exists($fbid, $offsets)) {
                                                            $offsets[$fbid] += $count;
                                                    }
                                            }
                                    }
                                    else {
                                            printf("$fbid complete with ". 
                                                     $offsets[$fbid]." posts\n");
                                            unset($offsets[$fbid]);
                                    }
                            }
                            else {
                                    // how to stop requesting this single url?
                                    print_r($result);
                                    echo "--\n";
                                    $numurls--;
                            }
                    }
            } while (++$r && $numurls);
    }
```